# Missing sound on VMWare Fusion 3.1

Tags: sound, vmware

I recently upgraded my VMWare Fusion from 2.x to 3.1 and was running Ubuntu 10.04. I had not problems until the upgrade at which point the sound is not working at all.  It was fine in VMWare 2.x. I installed the VMWare Tools but it did not fix it. I would appreciate if someone could throw light on the issue.

Thanks

Comment: There are many, many layers in the audio stack where things could have gone awry.  I recommend that you use `ubuntu-bug alsa-base` from within your VMWare Fusion 3.1 instance.

Answer (score 2):

VMWARE Fusion is for MacOSX.

I run VMWARE Workstation 7.1.1 and sounds works fine on Ubuntu emulated instances. ;)